# convenience init の使い方がわからない

Tags: swift

SwiftでCVPixelBufferをUIImageに変換するにあたって以下の記事を参照しました。

[[swift] CVPixelBufferからCGImage、UIImageへ変換する](https://qiita.com/tommy19970714/items/bc50d49fcb378c196d4f)

UIImageを以下のように拡張しているのですが、どうやって使えば良いか分かりません。

```
extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)

        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return nil
        } 
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

以下のような形で試してみたのですが、どうも使い方が違うようで、エラーが出ます。

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
{
    guard let currentFrame = session.currentFrame else { return }
    let capturedImage = currentFrame.capturedImage
    let capturedUIImage = UIImage(pixelBuffer:capturedImage)
}
```

エラー内容は、`No exact matches in call to initializer` というものです。
convenience initとは何なのでしょうか？どのように使うものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UIImageを以下のように拡張している

拡張を定義したファイルがプロジェクト(Swiftコンパイラ)から見えていないようです。

`ViewController`と同じファイルに以下の定義をおいても、ご質問に書かれたエラーは発生しません。

```
import ARKit

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        guard let currentFrame = session.currentFrame else { return }
        let capturedImage = currentFrame.capturedImage
        guard let capturedUIImage = UIImage(pixelBuffer: capturedImage) else {
            return
        }
        //...
    }
}

import VideoToolbox

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)

        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

(`UIImage`のextensionを古いSwiftでもコンパイルできるよう修正したコード。)

```
import VideoToolbox

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)

        guard let theCGImage = cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: theCGImage)
    }
}
```

---

使う側から見れば、convenienceイニシャライザは普通の`init`と変わりません。ただし、自分でサブクラスのイニシャライザを書こうと思うと、designatedイニシャライザとconvenienceイニシャライザの違いは、知らなくてはすまない基本なので、実際にコードを書く前にきちんと学習しておかれることをお勧めします。

[Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216)

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問内容と少しずれるかもしれませんが、このコードをViewControllerに移行すると、UIImage()...の箇所ではエラーがでなくなったものの、guard let cgImage  = cgImageの箇所でconflictが起きてエラーになってしまいます。これは同じ変数に同じ変数を代入しているように見えます。何をやっているのでしょうか。

Comment: @gncc さん、少し古いXcodeをお使い(あるいは新しいベータ版)なのではないでしょうか。最新のリリース版であるXcode 12.5.1では、問題なくコンパイルされます。`guard let`もSwiftの基本の一つですからご自分で調べてみてください。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり12.4ではエラーになりましたが、12.5では問題なく使用できました

Comment: @gncc さん、ご確認ありがとうございます。「このコードをViewControllerに移行すると」と記載されていますが、エラーになるかどうかはどのファイルに置くかどうかではなく、どのSwiftコンパイラを使うかだけが問題のはずです。Xcode 12.5.1でコンパイルできることがSwiftの言語仕様的に正しいと言えるかどうか怪しいので、一応古いSwiftコンパイラでもコンパイルできるようなコードも示しておきます。